# File reading in C starts from the middle of the file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read in a file and printing it all out but for some reason it starts doing so from almost the middle of the file, I've tried a few different methods of reading but none of them work as expected. This is the code. Thank you in advance.

```
void readFile(FILE *file) {
    FILE * fd = fopen((const char *) file, "r");

    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
    }

    char line[500];

    while (!feof(fd)) {
        fgets(line, 500, fd);
        printf("%s",line);
    } 

    fclose(fd);
}

int main() {

    readFile((FILE *) "ulysses.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `(FILE *) "ulysses.txt"` the argument is a const char * and the function should accept a const char *

Comment: Please replace `while (!feof(fd)) { fgets(line, 500, fd);` with `while (fgets(line, 500, fd) != NULL) {` etc and see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: The file name is a string, which should be passed to a `char*` string argument. `void readFile(char *file)`. The casting is hiding the errors.